# How check if a node exists in Java using conditional operator?

Tags: java

```
Node curr;
if(curr) sop(curr.data)
```

This is throwing an error that `Node` cannot be converted to `boolean`. Can anyone please suggest a way to check if the node exist or not?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it as:

```
Node curr; 

if(curr != null) {
    sop(curr.data)
}
```

The reason is unlike C++, we can not use objects as booleans in case they are null.

Comment: Thanks for your help,it worked!